# In Loop Output Place Custom Field Content In Between Paragraphs

Tags: loop, the-content

I'd like to place the contents of a custom field or variable in between the second and third paragraphs in the loop on a page template.

Is there a way to do this?

So for example, on a client's website I would like them to use the post editor to write out their page content, and keep things simple for them by giving them the ability to write out a call to action in a custom field that diplays between two paragraphs of

```
the_content();
```

using either a plugin or a PHP snippet or filter in functions.php.

Thanks very much.

Comment: There are no paragraphs in the loop, so use a shortcode.

Comment: Well the loop output contains paragraphs.  I could have asked that question more clearly.

Comment: `post_content` does not inherently contain paragraphs, it only contains paragraphs if `wp_auto_p` is enabled, and even then it is not a sure thing. Is there a reason that the element cannot be placed with CSS alone?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the additional info. What I'm trying to do is simplify things for a client.  I have a custom field that the client is using to create content for a blockquote.  I would like to have the blockquote appear after the second paragraph and I didn't want to have to use two editors to create the separate paragraphs.  So I'm looking to filter the the_content() output and place the contents (and otherwise styled div) of the custom field in between the second and third paragraphs.

Comment: I did find something, but I'm not sure where to place the code?  Do I place it here, or do I answer my own question, or edit the original question.

Comment: Answer your own question if you think it's right and accept it. I think you should use `the_content` filter to count `p` tag and insert custom field after second p. Or use a short tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this, here is what works for me:

```
<?php
$paragraphAfter= 1; //show box after selected paragraph
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
for ($i = 0; $i <count($content); $i++) {
if ($i == $paragraphAfter) { ?>
<!-- START OF BLOCKQUOTE -->
stuff
<!-- END OF BLOCKQUOTE -->
<?php
}
echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
} ?>
```